# Mongodb is unable to initiallize afer changing image to run as non-root

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

I'm trying to change my mongo pod to run as non-root. I've modified the mongodb image so it will use the already-existing `mongodb` user as its running user.

Existing environments that were just upgraded from root to non-root work as expected but clean envs that need to initialize the DB are failing to start. The DB is up but we see errors like:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T16:00:08.859+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":20251,   "ctx":"conn6","msg":"Supported SASL mechanisms requested for unknown user","attr":{"user":"root@admin"}}

{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T16:00:08.859+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":20249,   "ctx":"conn6","msg":"Authentication failed","attr":{"mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-256","speculative":true,"principalName":"root","authenticationDatabase":"admin","remote":"10.32.0.8:48838","extraInfo":{},"error":"UserNotFound: Could not find user \"root\" for db \"admin\""}}
```

As part of the dockerfile I'm creating `/home/mongodb` folder as it doesn't exist and changing it's ownership to `mongodb` (`999`).
My entrypoint looks like this:
`docker-entrypoint.sh mongod --keyFile /replica.key --replSet rs0 --oplogSize 991 --wiredTigerCacheSizeGB ${WIRE_TIGER_CACHE_SIZE_GB:-5}`

Attaching the output of the initial run:

```html
Starting mongo with CPU affinity 0-15
Wed Jul 20 15:58:31 UTC 2022 Waiting for mongo to come up.. (elapsed 0 sec)
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 41

{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:31.545+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20698,   "ctx":"main","msg":"***** SERVER RESTARTED *****"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:31.549+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:31.551+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:31.551+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:31.552+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":41,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"<host_name>"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:31.552+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.8","gitVersion":"83b8bb8b6b325d8d8d3dfd2ad9f744bdad7d6ca0","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu2004","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:31.552+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"20.04"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:31.552+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"net":{"bindIp":"127.0.0.1","port":27017,"tls":{"mode":"disabled"}},"processManagement":{"fork":true,"pidFilePath":"/tmp/docker-entrypoint-temp-mongod.pid"},"replication":{"oplogSizeMB":991},"storage":{"wiredTiger":{"engineConfig":{"cacheSizeGB":5.0}}},"systemLog":{"destination":"file","logAppend":true,"path":"/proc/20/fd/1"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:31.553+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22297,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine. See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:31.553+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=5120M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress,compact_progress],"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.195+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1658332712:195207][41:0x7fafa0e03cc0], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY | WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Set global recovery timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.195+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1658332712:195289][41:0x7fafa0e03cc0], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY | WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Set global oldest timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.204+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger opened","attr":{"durationMillis":651}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.204+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"RECOVERY", "id":23987,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp","attr":{"recoveryTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":0,"i":0}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.219+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4366408, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"No table logging settings modifications are required for existing WiredTiger tables","attr":{"loggingEnabled":true}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.219+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22262,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Timestamp monitor starting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.225+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22120,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.226+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20320,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"createCollection","attr":{"namespace":"admin.system.version","uuidDisposition":"provided","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"08107524-c8fb-4da8-affb-1cfcc72b7d83"}},"options":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"08107524-c8fb-4da8-affb-1cfcc72b7d83"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.238+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"INDEX",    "id":20345,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Index build: done building","attr":{"buildUUID":null,"namespace":"admin.system.version","index":"_id_","commitTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":0,"i":0}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.238+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":20459,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Setting featureCompatibilityVersion","attr":{"newVersion":"4.4"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.238+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20536,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Flow Control is enabled on this deployment"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.239+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20320,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"createCollection","attr":{"namespace":"local.startup_log","uuidDisposition":"generated","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"9e81081d-eef6-484b-b7a6-fc9794eaeb99"}},"options":{"capped":true,"size":10485760}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.253+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"INDEX",    "id":20345,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Index build: done building","attr":{"buildUUID":null,"namespace":"local.startup_log","index":"_id_","commitTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":0,"i":0}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.254+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":20625,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture","attr":{"dataDirectory":"/data/db/diagnostic.data"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.256+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20712,   "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheReap","msg":"Sessions collection is not set up; waiting until next sessions reap interval","attr":{"error":"NamespaceNotFound: config.system.sessions does not exist"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.256+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.256+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"127.0.0.1"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.256+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23016,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Waiting for connections","attr":{"port":27017,"ssl":"off"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.256+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20320,   "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheRefresh","msg":"createCollection","attr":{"namespace":"config.system.sessions","uuidDisposition":"generated","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"7225581d-4817-4307-abeb-1920af7690c8"}},"options":{}}}
child process started successfully, parent exiting
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.278+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"INDEX",    "id":20345,   "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheRefresh","msg":"Index build: done building","attr":{"buildUUID":null,"namespace":"config.system.sessions","index":"_id_","commitTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":0,"i":0}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.278+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"INDEX",    "id":20345,   "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheRefresh","msg":"Index build: done building","attr":{"buildUUID":null,"namespace":"config.system.sessions","index":"lsidTTLIndex","commitTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":0,"i":0}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.327+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:48808","connectionId":1,"connectionCount":1}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.327+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn1","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:48808","client":"conn1","doc":{"application":{"name":"MongoDB Shell"},"driver":{"name":"MongoDB Internal Client","version":"4.4.8"},"os":{"type":"Linux","name":"Ubuntu","architecture":"x86_64","version":"20.04"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.332+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn1","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:48808","connectionId":1,"connectionCount":0}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.509+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:48810","connectionId":2,"connectionCount":1}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.510+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:48810","client":"conn2","doc":{"application":{"name":"MongoDB Shell"},"driver":{"name":"MongoDB Internal Client","version":"4.4.8"},"os":{"type":"Linux","name":"Ubuntu","architecture":"x86_64","version":"20.04"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.552+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20320,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"createCollection","attr":{"namespace":"admin.system.users","uuidDisposition":"generated","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"d4e45e8c-5461-4187-b211-7d6222831bd5"}},"options":{}}}
Wed Jul 20 15:58:32 UTC 2022 Waiting for mongo to come up.. (elapsed 1 sec)
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.572+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"INDEX",    "id":20345,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"Index build: done building","attr":{"buildUUID":null,"namespace":"admin.system.users","index":"_id_","commitTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":0,"i":0}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.572+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"INDEX",    "id":20345,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"Index build: done building","attr":{"buildUUID":null,"namespace":"admin.system.users","index":"user_1_db_1","commitTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":0,"i":0}}}}
Successfully added user: {
    "user" : "root",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "root",
            "db" : "admin"
        }
    ]
}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.576+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:48810","connectionId":2,"connectionCount":0}}

/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*


{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.602+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20698,   "ctx":"main","msg":"***** SERVER RESTARTED *****"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.602+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.605+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.606+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
killing process with pid: 41
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.606+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23377,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Received signal","attr":{"signal":15,"error":"Terminated"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.606+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23378,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Signal was sent by kill(2)","attr":{"pid":104,"uid":999}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.606+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23381,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"will terminate after current cmd ends"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.606+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784900, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":10000}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.606+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the MirrorMaestro"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.606+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784902, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the WaitForMajorityService"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.607+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784903, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the LogicalSessionCache"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.607+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":20562,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutdown: going to close listening sockets"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.607+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23017,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"removing socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.607+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784905, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the global connection pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.607+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4784906, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the FlowControlTicketholder"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.607+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20520,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.607+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4784908, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the PeriodicThreadToAbortExpiredTransactions"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.607+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4784934, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the PeriodicThreadToDecreaseSnapshotHistoryCachePressure"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.607+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784909, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicationCoordinator"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.608+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784910, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the ShardingInitializationMongoD"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.608+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784911, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Enqueuing the ReplicationStateTransitionLock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.608+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784912, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Killing all operations for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.608+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4695300, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Interrupted all currently running operations","attr":{"opsKilled":3}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.608+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784913, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down all open transactions"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.608+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784914, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Acquiring the ReplicationStateTransitionLock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.608+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"INDEX",    "id":4784915, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the IndexBuildsCoordinator"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.608+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784916, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Reacquiring the ReplicationStateTransitionLock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.608+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784917, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Attempting to mark clean shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.608+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784918, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.608+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784921, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.608+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784925, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down free monitoring"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.608+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20609,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down free monitoring"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.608+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4784927, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the HealthLog"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.608+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4784929, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Acquiring the global lock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.608+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4784930, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the storage engine"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.608+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22320,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down journal flusher thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.608+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22321,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Finished shutting down journal flusher thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.608+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20282,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Deregistering all the collections"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.608+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22261,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Timestamp monitor shutting down"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.608+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22317,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"WiredTigerKVEngine shutting down"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.610+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22318,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down session sweeper thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.610+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22319,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Finished shutting down session sweeper thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.610+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22322,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down checkpoint thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.610+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22323,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Finished shutting down checkpoint thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.610+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795902, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Closing WiredTiger","attr":{"closeConfig":"leak_memory=true,"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.612+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1658332712:612025][41:0x7fafa0e02700], close_ckpt: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 47, snapshot max: 47 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0) base write gen: 1"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.645+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795901, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"WiredTiger closed","attr":{"durationMillis":35}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.646+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22279,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"shutdown: removing fs lock..."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.646+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784931, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.646+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":4784926, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down full-time data capture"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.646+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":20626,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down full-time diagnostic data capture"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.646+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Now exiting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T15:58:32.646+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":0}}
Wed Jul 20 15:58:33 UTC 2022 Waiting for mongo to come up.. (elapsed 2 sec)
```

It will then continue for 3 minutes until it reaches timeout. the command behind is trying to connect to the db and run a query and it's unable. after the pods reset I see the user doesn't exist errors.

I'd appreciate any help/hint that will guide me to finding the root cause of this issue.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We eventually found the issue. We had a `mongorc.js` script that we moved to the `/home/mongodb` directory; we configured a database to use there, and it used that file on the initialization of the database. We changed the `entrypoint` script so it moves the script to the `homedir` of the `mongodb` user only after the database is initialized, and now everything works again!